# How to show route between two points using google map v2

Tags: android, google-maps, maproute

I want to show a route between two points in Google Maps V2. I am able to achieve this with V1 but Google Map V2 does not support geopoints. So what should I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14702621/answer-draw-path-between-two-points-using-google-maps-android-api-v2

Comment: @nitish patel follow the link given by Archie.bpgc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can draw Polylines for routes. Docs here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays#Drawing_Polylines

If you mean drawing an actual route that you see in Google Maps directions, read the discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922086/google-map-static-drawing-route-instead-of-straight-line). Basically you'll need to utilize [DirectionService](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/reference.html#DirectionsService)