# using google Static Maps API drawing a path but some of them are irregular. why?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3

i want to draw a path from different origins to different destinations. i have all the starting and ending position but don't know why some of the path are drawn accurately and some them are off-trail.

i am getting image from this URI: i am getting image from this URI: "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=31.5521479,74.2795505&zoom=14&size=400x330&path=color:0x0000ff80|weight:5|31.5521479,74.2795505|31.5522324,74.2754122|31.5522324,74.2754122|31.5501177,74.2754083|31.5501177,74.2754083|31.5511665,74.2705363|31.5511665,74.2705363|31.5388245,74.2648314|31.5388245,74.2648314|31.4684959,74.2276782|31.4684959,74.2276782|31.4695281,74.2345655|31.4695281,74.2345655|31.4730443,74.2493176|31.4730443,74.2493176|31.4800704,74.2786811|31.4800704,74.2786811|31.4808300,74.2807995|31.4808300,74.2807995|31.4684399,74.2671173|31.4684399,74.2671173|31.4672701,74.2675231|31.4672701,74.2675231|31.4673295,74.2677900+&sensor=true&maptype=roadmap"

[image: My application + Google Map]

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: i have updated the question you can get the part of code you required.

Comment: It looks like your URI contains plot points for the path - how did you generate this URI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map static drawing "route" instead of straight line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922086/google-map-static-drawing-route-instead-of-straight-line)

Comment: @Charleh you can get it from google Direction API.

Comment: @DominicKexel not i am defining a complete path. not only the Source and destination.

Comment: What you see in the small map is the path defined by you, nothing more, nothing less. When you want a more precise path, you must add more details(LatLng's)

Comment: @Dr.Molle if any detail was missing then how the path from point.1 to point.2 is drawn so perfectly.

Comment: As I said, you get what you have defined, I can't tell you anything about the path seen in the screenshot,but the path defined for the staticmap(it's definitly not the same path as seen on the screenshot) did not define any points at the  marked straight line. Take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/nD9a6/show/ , that's your path, the markers are placed at the vertices for the path that you have defined. You might say there are a lot of point's missing, but you have defined each point(except the first and last) twice. The markers at the fiddle are draggable..drag them and you'll see it.

Comment: thanx @Dr.Molle i already gotten your point but i was getting these details from Get Direction API.