# Drawing a route on static google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Hi guys im currently working with the Google map Direction API, its pretty neat but i have a problem on this [site](http://remedia-solutions.com/clientes/0078_Vistadesarrollos/pruebamapa.php)

If you type any place on the input and then click on the button it will draw you the route, and if you click "Link al mapa" it will take you to a static map of that route,but it just draw a big line between both points instead of the route.

Any idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question seems to be a duplicate of [google map static drawing "route" instead of straight line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3922086/google-map-static-drawing-route-instead-of-straight-line). It seems possible. On that page, you'll find directions to achieve what you want.

Comment: I decided to send the parameters to the google site, but your answer works ;D